# Should I use 'use server' in all functions that fetch secret data within server components in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-server-components

Server components are enabled by default in Next.js 13. I'm wondering if I need to wrap each fetch in a separate function and add 'use server' to it to hide the function's code, or can I simply use fetch in the same function that returns the TSX?

Code wrap with function and 'use server':

```
async function getData() {
  'use server'
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/test',{cache:'no-cache'})

  return res.json()
}

interface Test{
  age:number,
  name:string,
  likes:number,
}
 
export default async  function Home() {

  const tests:Test[] = await getData()

  return (
   <div className='flex flex-row'>
    {tests.map((test)=>{
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
          {test.name}
          </div>
          <div>
          {test.age}
          </div>
          <div>
          Likes: {test.likes}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Code without 'use server':

```
interface Test {
  age:number,
  name:string,
  likes:number,
}
 
export default async  function Home() {

  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/test',{cache:'no-cache'})

  const tests:Test[] = await res.json()

  return (
   <div className='flex flex-row'>
    {tests.map((test)=>{
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
          {test.name}
          </div>
          <div>
          {test.age}
          </div>
          <div>
          Likes: {test.likes}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Which of these versions is more secure, and when should each be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, within the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, Next.js uses Server Components by default (until a `"use client"` is added at the top). They get called on the server, and returned to the browser as HTML (containing what's in the JSX, the `return` part). No JavaScript code from the component reaches the browser: ***you don't have to do or add anything***.

The `"use server"` is introduced for a specific feature of the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, called [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations), where out of functions (with `"use server"`) passed to form elements, you get API routes.

It may seem odds, but `"use server"` is not the opposite of `"use client"`. A component with no `"use client"` at the top is the opposite of `"use client"`. And `"use server"` is totally different.